# How to write below multithreaded program best way

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multithreading, and get to know about the functionality of wait, notify and notifyAll. I want three threads to execute one after another and print alphabets from A to Z.
I have tried below code and it seems working also, but I doubt if this is the best possible way to tackle the problem. Is there any other way, I can make it more simple and better ? It seems some portion of my code is repeating.

```
package demo.threading;

class Flags {

    boolean flagA = true;
    boolean flagB = false;
    boolean flagC = false;

}

class Container {

    Flags flags = new Flags();
    int charVal = (int) 'A';

    void producer1() {

        try {
            while (charVal <= (int) 'Z') {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (!flags.flagA)
                        wait();
                    else {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Produced : " + (char) charVal);
                        flags.flagA = false;
                        flags.flagB = true;
                        charVal++;
                        notifyAll();
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    void producer2() {

        try {
            while (charVal <= (int) 'Z') {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (!flags.flagB)
                        wait();
                    else {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Produced : " + (char) charVal);
                        flags.flagB = false;
                        flags.flagC = true;
                        charVal++;
                        notifyAll();
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void producer3() {

        try {
            while (charVal <= (int) 'Z') {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (!flags.flagC)
                        wait();
                    else {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Produced : " + (char) charVal);
                        flags.flagC = false;
                        flags.flagA = true;
                        charVal++;
                        notifyAll();
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Container container = new Container();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> container.producer1(), "Thread 1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> container.producer2(), "Thread 2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> container.producer3(), "Thread 3");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

    }
}
```

Output should be :

```
Thread 1 Produced : A
Thread 2 Produced : B
Thread 3 Produced : C
Thread 1 Produced : D
Thread 2 Produced : E
Thread 3 Produced : F
```

Comment: The best way to print the alphabet three times is `System.out.println("ABC...XYZABC...XYZABC...XYZ")`; or whatever order you're trying to achieve. The problem with trying to learn multithreading from examples like this is that they simply don't need multithreading.

Comment: Outside the fact that this example is somewhat senseless: `wait`should be used in a loop - **"As in the one argument version, interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop"** from [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) Your catch-block would simply end the thread and thus not handling a spurious Interrupt correctly.

Comment: @Fildor, Hi, Thanks for your feedback, Can you please suggest any better sensible way to achieve the same :)

Comment: As Andy writes: The example is pretty bad because the easiest way would be not to used multithreading. I just wanted to give the hint that if you want to force multithreading and usage of wait/notify here, then you should use it according to the suggestions in the documentation(see the link in above comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package demo.thread;

public class ABCPuzzle {

    private static class RunnableImpl implements Runnable {

        private String nextThread;
        private ExecServ execServ;

        public RunnableImpl(ExecServ execServ, String nextThread) {
            this.execServ = execServ;
            this.nextThread = nextThread;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();

            synchronized (execServ) {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        if (execServ.key > 'Z')
                            break;

                        if (threadName.equals(execServ.current)) {
                            System.out.println(threadName + " consuming "  + execServ.key);
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            execServ.key++;
                            execServ.current = nextThread;
                            execServ.notifyAll();
                        } else
                            execServ.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class ExecServ {
        private String current, next;
        private char key = 'A';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecServ execServ = new ExecServ();
        execServ.current = "t1";

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new RunnableImpl(execServ, "t2"), "t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new RunnableImpl(execServ, "t3"), "t2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new RunnableImpl(execServ, "t4"), "t3");
        Thread t4 = new Thread(new RunnableImpl(execServ, "t1"), "t4");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

    }
}
```

Output :

```
t1 consuming A
t2 consuming B
t3 consuming C
t4 consuming D
t1 consuming E
t2 consuming F
t3 consuming G
t4 consuming H
t1 consuming I
t2 consuming J
```

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out before, if you want to do this "one after another", you actually don't need multiple threads. However, you can achieve this by using a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html):

```java
int numberOfThreads = 3;
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfThreads; i++) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            for (char c : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray()) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                        + " produced: " + c + ".");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // NOP
        } finally {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }, "Thread " + i).start();
}
```

I recommend exploring [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) which is available since Java 5. It's a great help to keep your concurrent code concise and simple compared with Java's low-level concurrency primitives such as `wait` and `notify`. If you're really interested in that topic, [Brian Goetz's "Java Concurrency in Practice"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) is a must-read.

**EDIT:**

```java
public class ConcurrentAlphabet {

    private volatile Thread current;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConcurrentAlphabet().print(3,
                "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray());
    }

    public void print(int numberOfThreads, char[] alphabet) {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[numberOfThreads];

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfThreads; i++) {
            int offset = i - 1;
            threads[offset] = new Thread(() -> {
                Thread me = Thread.currentThread();
                Thread next = threads[(offset + 1) % numberOfThreads];

                for (int index = offset; index < alphabet.length; index += numberOfThreads) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        while (me != current) {
                            try {
                                wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* NOP */ }
                        }

                        System.out.println(me.getName() + " produced: " + alphabet[index] + ".");
                        current = next;
                        notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            }, "Thread " + i);
        }

        current = threads[0];

        for (Thread t : threads) {
            t.start();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, i have added expected output :)

Comment: @GoutamSingh: Are you open for alternate solutions or do you want to use `wait` and `notify`?

Comment: Any solution would be fine @beatngu13 :)

Comment: **Thank you very much** @beatngu13 :) This is what I was looking for

Comment: You'd at least need a volatile on the `current` variable.